# Is it valid to inject the $rootScope into Controller in order use or override models/method defined under $rootScope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I've defined some models in `App.run` below which I'm overriding within the controller `someCtrl`:

```
App.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.attempt = 1;
});

function someCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.attempt = 2;

  $rootScope.checkAttempt = function () {
    return $rootScope.attempt > 1 ? true : false;    
  };
}
```

There is a button on the page out of `someCtrl's` scope:

```
<button class='btn' ng-disabled="checkAttempt()">Who's changing my value?</button>
```

FYI, I'm aware of creating a service or using emit-broadcaste mechanism to share data across controllers but I would like to know How authenticate is it to inject $rootScope into a controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IMHO, I think its fine to inject `$rootScope` into a controller. I would recommend using emit/broadcast.

Comment: One thing about using rootScope is that you have the ability to broadcast down to all the child scopes. One other note and that is, when using scopes the best practice is to not attach directly onto the scope, meaning, create objects on scopes, so $rootScope.my = { attempt: 1 }. This is key for two-way data binding and you are less apt to lose binding.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to inject $rootScope into a controller. When you inject $scope, you automatically have access to anything defined in $rootScope due to scope inheritance. See [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/guide/scope). Scroll down to Scope Hierarchies section.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no harm in injecting a `$rootScope` into a controller, services or directives but you do try to figure out if its really necessary. The reason is that any method or property bound to `$rootScope` makes it global that will not be GC'ed unless manually cleaned up and it creates all those problems which global variables create.

The best way to share data across multiple controllers is to use a service.